# How to run .cntk file in pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, cntk

I am new in cntk and python and I do not know how or where in pyCharm execute command:

> cntk  configFile=ImageHandsOn.cntk

from tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Hands-On-Labs-Image-Recognition

CNTK and other libraries are configured correctly for Python 3.5.

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The link that you provided is the old Branscript language in CNTK, you can't use Brainsscript with PyCharm.

For Python please look at those tutorials: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Tutorials

Thanks,
Emad